# Current status of PCC (Portable C Compiler)?

Tags: compiler

PCC's current [website](http://pcc.ludd.ltu.se) (the development was taken over from the '70ies code from Stephen C. Johnson by Anders Magnusson, and mostly rewritten). It shows no activity in it's CVS repository ("cvs -d :pserver:anonymous@pcc.ludd.ltu.se:/cvsroot co pcc") since Sun May 19 01:00:02 2019 +0000. Anybody know what is going on? Did the development move elsewhere?

Comment: Some more comments did show up recently. False alarm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's only a couple of months, which is not an unusual gap in pcc's [commit history](https://marc.info/?l=pcc-commit-list). Perhaps you have unrealistic expectations for development activity on pcc.

Comment: I've been following PCC's history from CVS, and while there were frequent gaps of a few weeks lately, this is by far the longest I've seen.

Comment: @vonbrand There was a gap of more than three months a year ago, according to the commit mailing list (2018-04-12 to 2018-07-27. It's summer in Scandinavia. :-) Also a three-month gap from 2017-07-03 to 2017-10-03.